# Applying calculations to a dataframe where conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

**df**

```
     date           name        product                 items
0    2020-01-01     google          one                 224.0
2    2020-01-01     amazon          two                   4.0
3    2020-01-01     amazon        three                   8.0
1    2020-01-01     amazon         four                   4.0
0    2020-01-01     amazon          one                  17.0
..          ...     ...             ...                   ...
351  2020-03-27     google         five                   9.0
352  2020-03-27     google          six                   8.0
353  2020-03-27     google          one                 117.0
426  2020-03-27     amazon        three                  18.0
427  2020-03-27     amazon         four                   1.0
```

I am trying to apply simple multiplication on a new column `price` which has two conditions, for example:

- If name is google and product is one, then `items` * `100`
- If name is google and product is two, then `items` * `150`
- If name is amazon and product is one, then `items` * `50`

And so on.

How could I apply multiplications with two conditions? I assume simply filtering the `df` when applying calculations would do the job, right?

What I tried:

`df['price'[df['name']=='google' & df['product']] == 'one']= df['items'].apply(lambda x:x*100)`

But I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

How could I achieve applying calculations with two conditions met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one condition is possible change your solution with select mask both sides and multiple:

```
m = (df['name']=='google') & (df['product'] == 'one')
df.loc[m, 'price'] = df.loc[m, 'items'] * 100
print (df)
           date    name product  items    price
0    2020-01-01  google     one  224.0  22400.0
2    2020-01-01  amazon     two    4.0      NaN
3    2020-01-01  amazon   three    8.0      NaN
1    2020-01-01  amazon    four    4.0      NaN
0    2020-01-01  amazon     one   17.0      NaN
351  2020-03-27  google    five    9.0      NaN
352  2020-03-27  google     six    8.0      NaN
353  2020-03-27  google     one  117.0  11700.0
426  2020-03-27  amazon   three   18.0      NaN
427  2020-03-27  amazon    four    1.0      NaN
```

If few conditions use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = (df['name']=='google') & (df['product'] == 'one')
m2 = (df['name']=='google') & (df['product'] == 'two')

df['price'] = np.select([m1, m2], [100, 150], default=np.nan) * df['items']
print (df)
           date    name product  items    price
0    2020-01-01  google     one  224.0  22400.0
2    2020-01-01  amazon     two    4.0      NaN
3    2020-01-01  amazon   three    8.0      NaN
1    2020-01-01  amazon    four    4.0      NaN
0    2020-01-01  amazon     one   17.0      NaN
351  2020-03-27  google    five    9.0      NaN
352  2020-03-27  google     six    8.0      NaN
353  2020-03-27  google     one  117.0  11700.0
426  2020-03-27  amazon   three   18.0      NaN
427  2020-03-27  amazon    four    1.0      NaN
```

If many coditions is possible create new `DataFrame` and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({  'name':['google','google','amazon'],
                   'product':['one','two','one'],
                      'mult':[100, 150, 50]})

df1 = df.merge(df1, on=['name','product'], how='left')
df1['price'] = df1['mult'] *  df1['items']
print (df1)
         date    name product  items   mult    price
0  2020-01-01  google     one  224.0  100.0  22400.0
1  2020-01-01  amazon     two    4.0    NaN      NaN
2  2020-01-01  amazon   three    8.0    NaN      NaN
3  2020-01-01  amazon    four    4.0    NaN      NaN
4  2020-01-01  amazon     one   17.0   50.0    850.0
5  2020-03-27  google    five    9.0    NaN      NaN
6  2020-03-27  google     six    8.0    NaN      NaN
7  2020-03-27  google     one  117.0  100.0  11700.0
8  2020-03-27  amazon   three   18.0    NaN      NaN
9  2020-03-27  amazon    four    1.0    NaN      NaN
```